# Drupal - Devel Themer and SimpleHTMLdom causing timeouts after activation

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, simple-html-dom

I'm attempting to use Devel Themer with Drupal 7.

SimpleHTMLdom (1.12) activates without a problem, upon activating Devel Themer I'm hit with a timeout error for line 798 in the `simple_html_dom.php` file. I increased the php execution time to 60 seconds and now I'm getting max memory errors for the same line.

> (Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted)
>   Something looks like it's stuck on a loop somewhere.

I cannot access permissions or module administration pages with devel themer activated. I have to restore a database backup to a point before the module was active to gain access to those pages.

**Any ideas or has anyone else have this issue before?**

I have searched, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Devel Themer needs a particular version of SimpleHTMLdom (7.x-1.12, not the latest), see https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer, could it be your problem ?

Comment: That is the version I am using.

Comment: I am having this same issue and have the right version of simplehtmldom installed:

Answer (score 0):

Putting this value in php.ini works for me. At least themer develop kinda works with lots of Ajax errors:

```
max_input_time = -1
```